# Drupal 6 create CRUD grid in settings form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, themes

I'm quite new to Drupal and I want to create a custom grid that has some editable columns, some other columns witch checkboxes etc.

I'm using the `theme()` function to create the table and render it at the settings. Since I cannot find any way to access the form/settings variables, inside the theme function, I create a custom table at the drupal database that will contain the gid values, and I render those rows. For testing purposes I fetch the 'variables' table rows. Here is the code so far:

```
 $form['module_settings']['profile_grid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => t('Profile Mapping'),
        '#theme' => 'profile_mapping_grid'
    );


function theme_profile_mapping_grid($sender) {
    $header = array('', t('name'), t('value'));
    $result = db_query('SELECT v.name, v.value from {variable} v');
    while ($pair = db_fetch_object($result)) { 
        $format = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => 30,
            '#value' => $pair->name
        );
        $hhfield = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => 30,
            '#value' => $pair->value
        );
        $row = array('');
        $row[] = drupal_render($format);
        $row[] = drupal_render($hhfield);
        $rows[] = array('data' => $row);    
    }

    $output = theme('table', $header, $rows, array('id' => 'gridErrors'));
    return $output;
}
```

The grid is generated correctly, but I have an issue. I cannot set the 'name' attribute to the textfield, in order to collect it's value later on, on a submit action. 
Furthermore, I'm not sure if this is the best way to create a settings grid.

Any ideas, opinions etc are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Drupal 6 Form API Quickstart Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/751826):

> 5. Don't use the '#value' attribute for any form element that can be changed by the user. Use the '#default_value' attribute instead. Don't put values from  $form_state['values'] (or $_POST) here! FormsAPI will deal with that for you; only put the original value of the field here.

You have to use `'#default_value' => $pair->name` not `'#value' => $pair->value`.

Here is the sample module with settings table.

install file:

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * @file
 * The your_module module install file, which handles the install/uninstall tasks.
 *
 */

function your_module_install() {
  // Create tables.
  drupal_install_schema('your_module');
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema().
 */
function your_module_schema() {

/* Settings table */
$schema['your_module_settings'] = array(
    'description' => 'Stores module settings.',
    'fields' => array(
        'record_id' => array(
            'description' => 'The primary identifier for a record.',
            'type' => 'serial', 
            'unsigned' => TRUE, 
            'not null' => TRUE),
        'item_code' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar', 
            'length' => '255', 
            'not null' => TRUE),
        'setting_one' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar', 
            'length' => '255', 
            'not null' => TRUE),
        'setting_two' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar', 
            'length' => '255')),
    'unique keys' => array(
        'record_id' => array('record_id')),
    'primary key' => array('record_id')
);

  return $schema;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_uninstall().
 */
function your_module_uninstall() {
  // Remove tables.
  drupal_uninstall_schema('your_module');
}
```

module file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_help()
 */
function your_module_help($path, $arg) 
{
  switch ($path) 
  {
    case 'admin/help#your_module':
      return '<p>'. t('Module description.') .'</p>';
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function your_module_menu()
{
  $items = array();

  /* module settings page */
  $items['admin/settings/your_module'] = array(
    'description' => 'Administer your_module module settings.',
    'title' => 'Some title',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('your_module_admin_settings'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function your_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'your_module_products_settings' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Settings form
 */
function your_module_admin_settings(&$form_state)
{
  $form['your_module'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Settings'),
      '#description' => t('Settings description.'),
    );

  $form['your_module']['products_settings_table'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'your_module_products_settings',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );

  $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'] = array();

  $result = db_query('SELECT record_id, item_code, setting_one, setting_two  FROM {your_module_settings} ORDER BY item_code');

  while ($product_setting = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'][$product_setting->record_id] = array();

    $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'][$product_setting->record_id]['item_code'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $product_setting->item_code,
      '#size' => 8,
      '#maxlength' => 16,
    );

    $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'][$product_setting->record_id]['setting_one'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $product_setting->setting_one,
      '#size' => 16,
      '#maxlength' => 16,
    );

    $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'][$product_setting->record_id]['setting_two'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $product_setting->setting_two,
      '#size' => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
  }

  /* "add new row" fields */
  $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new'] = array();

  /* new item_code */
  $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new']['item_code'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 8,
    '#maxlength' => 16,
    '#description' => t('description'),
  );

  /* new setting_one */
  $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new']['setting_one'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 16,
    '#maxlength' => 16,
    '#description' => t('description'),
  );

  /* setting_two */
  $form['your_module']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new']['setting_two'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 40,
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    '#description' => t('description'),
  );

  /* Submit button */
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save Settings'),
    '#name' => 'SubmitButton',
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Custom theme function for a table of products settings
 */
function theme_your_module_products_settings($form) {
  $header = array(t('Item Code'), t('Setting One'), t('Setting Two'));
  $rows = array();

  /* saved rows */
  foreach (element_children($form['products_settings']) as $key) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = drupal_render($form['products_settings'][$key]['item_code']);
    $row[] = drupal_render($form['products_settings'][$key]['setting_one']);
    $row[] = drupal_render($form['products_settings'][$key]['setting_two']);
    $rows[] = $row;
  }

  /* new row to add */
  $row = array();
  $row[] = drupal_render($form['products_settings_new']['item_code']);
  $row[] = drupal_render($form['products_settings_new']['setting_one']);
  $row[] = drupal_render($form['products_settings_new']['setting_two']);
  $rows[] = $row;

  $output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Submission function for your_module_admin_settings form.
 */
function your_module_admin_settings_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  /* processing changes */
  if (isset($form_state['values']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'])) {
    foreach ($form_state['values']['products_settings_table']['products_settings'] as $record_id => $data) {
      if (empty($data['item_code']) && empty($data['setting_one']) && empty($data['setting_two'])) {
        /* delete saved row if all fields are empty */
        db_query("DELETE FROM {your_module_settings} WHERE record_id=%d", $record_id);

        drupal_set_message(t('Deleted.'), 'status');
      }
      else {
        /* update */
        db_query("UPDATE {your_module_settings} SET item_code='%s', setting_one='%s', setting_two='%s' WHERE record_id=%d",
          $data['item_code'], $data['setting_one'], $data['setting_two'], $record_id);
      }
    }
  }

  /* adding new row */
  $item_code = $form_state['values']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new']['item_code'];
  $setting_one = $form_state['values']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new']['setting_one'];
  $setting_two = $form_state['values']['products_settings_table']['products_settings_new']['setting_two'];

  if (!empty($item_code) && !empty($setting_one) && !empty($setting_two)) {

    db_query("INSERT INTO {your_module_settings} (item_code, setting_one, setting_two) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
        $item_code, $setting_one, $setting_two);

    drupal_set_message(t('Added new setting.'), 'status');
  }

  drupal_set_message(t('Settings updated.'), 'status');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're generating the fields in the theme function and it will not work because the submit function will only act on the fields generated by your form function.

The correct way is to generate all fields in the form function (basically what you're doing now in the theme function) and render them in the theme using drupal_render.

> Since I cannot find any way to access the form/settings variables, inside the theme function

The form is passed to the theme function as an argument, in your case $sender, and that's how you access them.

Here's some code, untested, but you get the idea. Remember that the call `$output .= drupal_render($form);` is very important because it renders the hidden fields needed by the Form API such as the form_id and the CSRF protection. Without this call submit won't work.

```php
function mymodule_grid_form($form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['variables'] = array();

    $result = db_query('SELECT v.name, v.value from {variable} v');
    while ($pair = db_fetch_object($result)) { 
        $form['variables'][$pair->name][$pair->name . '_name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => 30,
            '#value' => $pair->name
        );
        $form['variables'][$pair->name][$pair->name . '_value'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => 30,
            '#value' => $pair->value
        );
    }

    return $form;
}

function theme_mymodule_grid_form($form) {
    $header = array('', t('name'), t('value'));

    foreach ($form['variables'] as $variable => $values) {
        $row = array('');
        $row[] = drupal_render($values[$variable . '_name']);
        $row[] = drupal_render($values[$variable . '_value']);
        $rows[] = array('data' => $row); 
    }

    $output = theme('table', $header, $rows, array('id' => 'gridErrors'));
    $output .= drupal_render($form);
    return $output;
}

function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_grid_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... A table is rendered at the top of the settings form with the correct values, and the values are dumped again without a table at the specific fieldset I want them to be. Moreover the table has twice the rows of the available rows (the other half are empty). I followed your example except the `$row` needs 
`$value = $values[$variable . '_value'];
..
$row = drupal_render($value)`
How is the form supposed to know at what fieldset to render the table?